# Ridiculously slow Apps-Script Loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've just switched from excel to Google sheets and I've had to go through a bit of a learning curve with moving on with "Macros" or scripts as they're now called.

Anyway, a short while later I've written a loop to go through everything in column B and if it's less than 50, delete the row.

It works and I'm happy but it's so slow. I have about 16,000 rows and I'll probably end with more. I let it run for about 4 minutes and it didn't even get rid of 1,000 rows. I refuse to believe that a popular programming language is that slow I can still read stuff as it's being deleted 20 rows up.

```
function grabData(){  
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Keywords");
  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  let range = sheet.getRange("B2:B16000");
  let values=range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i<len;  i++){
    if(values[i] <= 50 ){
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
      i--
      len--
    };
  };
}
```

I keep seeing somewhere that something's not being reset, but I have no idea what that means.

Is it because the array length starts off at 16,000 and when I delete a row I'm not accounting for it properly?

Comment: Presumably https://yagisanatode.com/2019/06/12/google-apps-script-delete-rows-based-on-a-columns-cell-value-in-google-sheet/ still applies?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but for such a simple task, wouldn't it be easier to just sort Col B least to greatest, select all rows less than 50 (which will all now be at the top) and then delete them manually? That would take about 30 seconds.

Comment: No you're not missing anything, it's all part of a bigger plan to automate all manual tasks. But the script for deleting rows is mind bendingly slow.

Answer (score 1):

Since I never use formulas I would do it this way:

```
function grabData() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sh = ss.getSheetByName("Keywords");
  let rg = s.getRange(2, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  let values = rg.getValues();
  let oA = [];
  values.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] > 50) {
      oA.push(r);
    }
  });
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

It's much faster but it will probably mess up your formulas.  Which is one of the reasons I never use formulas.  Deleting lines is quite slow.  Pretty much anything you do with the UI is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to App Script and the community! App Script is actually very fast if follow the *best practice* of App Script.

Here is an example for you that will complete what you need in one second (*modify the variable value in config to fit your own application):

```js
function myFunction() {
  // config
  const filterValue = 50
  const targetSheetName = "Sheet1"
  const targetColumn = "A"
  const startRowNum = "2"

  // get data from target sheet 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName)
  const endRowNum = sheet.getLastRow()
  const targetRange =`${targetColumn + startRowNum }:${targetColumn + endRowNum}`
  const data = sheet.getRange(targetRange).getValues()

  // filter data based on filterValue and set filtered result into new ary
  const ary = data.filter(row=>row[0]>=filterValue)
  
  //get max row number in the sheet
  const maxRowNum = sheet.getMaxRows()

  // break if nothing is filtered out
  if(ary.length===0){
    // remove all row and break
    let deleteStartFromRowNum = parseInt(startRowNum,10) - 1
    let deleteRowsCount = maxRowNum - deleteStartFromRowNum
    sheet.deleteRows(deleteStartFromRowNum, deleteRowsCount)
    return
  }
  // break if all is filtered out 
  if(ary.length===data.length){
    // remove all trailing empty rows
    if(endRowNum<maxRowNum){
      let deletStartFromRowNum = endRowNum+1
      let deleteRowsCount = maxRowNum-endRowNum
      sheet.deleteRows(deletStartFromRowNum,deleteRowsCount)
    }
    return
  }

  // get lowerbound (the last row of filtered data in ary)
  const lowerBound = parseInt(startRowNum,10) + ary.length - 1
  
  // set ary into sheet range according to lowerBound value
  sheet.getRange(`${targetColumn + startRowNum}:${targetColumn + lowerBound.toString()}`).setValues(ary)

  // delete rest of the rows that are below lower bound
  let deleteStartFromRowNum = lowerBound + 1
  let deleteRowsCount = maxRowNum - lowerBound
  sheet.deleteRows(deleteStartFromRowNum, deleteRowsCount)
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

In Apps Script, you want to minimize calls to other service, including requests to Spreadsheets (see [Minimize calls to other services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)). Calling other services in a loop will slow down your script considerably.

Because of this, it's much preferrable to filter out the undesired rows from `values`, remove all existing data in the range via [Range.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent()), and then use [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to write the filtered `values` back to the spreadsheet (see [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)).

#### Code snippet:

```
function grabData(){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Keywords");
  const range = sheet.getRange("B2:B16000");
  const values = range.getValues().filter(val => val[0] > 50);
  range.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2,2,values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)